# Existence of a Noncontinous $f$ Satisfying $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

Dose there a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying 
$f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)\quad\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$
But not of the form $f(x)= \lambda x$ ? 
Such $f$ must necessarily be discontinuous

Comment: @Ameryr Are you sure $e^{x+y}=e^x+e^y$?

Comment: @C.Falcon I don't think those are duplicates the linked question asks for *continuous functions*.

Comment: Oh sorry i deleted my comment